# Kivy Label: on_touch_down event is triggered everywhere in the screen

Tags: python, kivy

I want to trigger my function when I click on the label but actually, it is triggered on the button too ! (and on all the screen to be more precise).

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

KV = """
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: "BUTTON"
"""

class MyFirstKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.box = Builder.load_string(KV)
        l = Label(text="LABEL")
        l.bind(on_touch_down=self.label_click)
        self.box.add_widget(l)
        return self.box

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        super().on_kv_post(base_widget)


    def label_click(self, w,event):
        print("Am I only triggered when touching the label ?")

MyFirstKivyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not beautiful bur whatever... it works !

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

KV = """
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: "BUTTON"
"""

class MyFirstKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.box = Builder.load_string(KV)
        l = Label(text="LABEL")
        l.bind(on_touch_down=self.label_click)
        self.box.add_widget(l)
        return self.box

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        super().on_kv_post(base_widget)


    def label_click(self, w,touch):
        if w.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print("Am I only triggered when touching the label ?")

MyFirstKivyApp().run()
```

Comment: No need to check for collision on_ref_press works fine https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#interactive-zone-in-text

Answer (score 0):

Documentation can be found [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#interactive-zone-in-text)

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

KV = """
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: "BUTTON"
"""

class MyFirstKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.box = Builder.load_string(KV)
        l = Label(text="[ref=label]Label[/ref]", markup=True)
        l.bind(on_ref_press=self.label_click)
        self.box.add_widget(l)
        return self.box

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        super().on_kv_post(base_widget)


    def label_click(self, w,event):
        print("Am I only triggered when touching the label ?")

MyFirstKivyApp().run()
```